# почему не работет ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Расположение файлов:

1. `index.php` лежит в корне(ну думаю это и так понятно)
2. `myvxo_VH.js` подгружается в индексный файл из каталога `js/myvxo_VH.js`
3. `vxod.php` тоже лежит в корне.

Теперь сам код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#FormVsxod').click(function() {
    var user1 = $('#LogOtprav').val();
    var pas1 = $('#PasOtprav').val();
    /* Вариант 1
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "vxod.php",
      data: "user="+user1+"&pas="+pas1,
      success: function(msg){
        alert( msg );//данные
      }
    });
    */
    //Вариант 2
    $("#lsVH").load(
      "vxod.php", {
        user: user1,
        pas: pas1
      },
      function() {
        alert("Получен ответ от сервера.")
      }
    );

    //не тот не другой не работают. Единтсвенная
    //разница так это в 1 врианте всё таки вызывается алерт
    //но пустой, тоесть отсета от сервера нет
    //а во втором вообще никакой риакции.

  });

});
```

`index.php` не имеет ни одной строчки php кода. Лишь html и подключение скриптов.
А в `vxod.php` лишь одна строчка.

```
echo "Рас два три проверка".
```

---

Сделал так. Но не чего не вышло :/

```
$.post("/vxod.php",{'user' : user1, 'pas': pas1},onAjaxSuccess)};
function onAjaxSuccess(data){
alert(data);
}
```

Comment: Может стоит открыть консоль девелопера и узнать че там?

Comment: Ничего там нет. Ошибок не выдаёт говорит всё норм.

Comment: Самое первое что я бы проверил - это то, что функция обработки щелчка вызывается. Банальное добавление console.log("I'm click function"); в самое начало каждой функции может сильно помочь.

Comment: код вообще вызывается? форма `#FormVsxod` есть на странице? s скорее всего лишнее в V**s**hod

Comment: Там что точка в конце в echo?
`echo "Раз два три проверка";`

Comment: Форма есть. А в echo просто опечатка в конце там нет точки.
И функцию обработки я первым делом проверял. Да и я писал же что в 1 варианте alert вызывался но пустой. Так функц робит точно

Comment: т.е. в  1м варианте алерт вызывается, но если поставить бряк - msg пустой?

Comment: Может стоит прописать Content-type в vxod.php и dataType для myvxo_VH.js?

Comment: `"/vxod.php"`- может url стоит указывать так, если он не абсолютный

Comment: @user181105 воспользуйтесь отладчиком. посмотрите вкладку network  в dev tools браузера - уходил ли запрос, приходил ли ответ. посмотрите на тело ответа. поставьте брекпойнт в функции до и после вызова. пройдитесь по ней по шагам. не тратьте свое и чужое время на гадание.

Answer (score 1):

можно например так

```
function sendAJAX(user, pas) {   
$.post("/vxod.php",{'user' : user, 'pas': pas},onAjaxSuccess)}
```

`onAjaxSuccess` это ф-ция в которую пойдёт ответ от сервера

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/vxod.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({'user' : user1, 'pas': pas1}),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                success: function (data) {
                    //some code
                }
            });
```